# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[DEMO Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I6Qk.png)I am making a dynamic add row and dynamic selectbox option with using increment 'x' and 'i' value in two javascript function as the code below.Is working when select  to option 0.5 but when change it to 1 it come out Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZAdS.png)

```js
var x = 1;

function appendRow() {

  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + x);

  newTextBoxDiv.after().html("<div class='form-group'><label class='control-label col-sm-3'  style='text-align:right;'>Date:</label><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='input-group date' ><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></span><input type='Date' class='form-control'  name='Dates'> <select class='form-control' id='slct" + x + "' name='Branch' onchange='change();'><option  disabled=''  selected=''>Please Select Leave Day</option> <option value='1' >1</option><option value='0.5' >0.5</option></select></div></span></div><div id='container" + x + "'></div></div>");
  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#div");
  x++;
}

var i = 0;

function change() {
  i++;
  var select = document.getElementById("slct" + i);

  var divv = document.getElementById("container" + i);
  var value = select.value;

  if (value == 0.5) {
    toAppend = "<label class='control-label col-sm-1'>Time:</label><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'date'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control' ></div></div><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'dates'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control'  ></div></div>";
    divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
    return;
  }
  if (value == 1) {
    toAppend = "";
    divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="div">
  <button onclick="appendRow()" value="Add Row">Add row</button>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `0.5` is being read as a proper number and not as a string. You should try `parseFloat(0.5);

Comment: Yes it can be working without adding parseFloat  because it's no restriction whether it's string or float .

Comment: Just for kicks, try the following. Notice the space between the quotes.

`if (value== 1) {
            toAppend = " ";
            divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
        }`

Comment: Can you provide a working JSFiddle or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what went wrong. in your function called change() you are incrementing i. It increments every time you run it. This results into references to an id that does not exist, resulting in the error you got.

I made up a solution where you enter the relevant referential number in your function. just retrieve the number before you run the function. In this case after you made a change.

You should be able to figure it out from here. I also entered some comments in the code explaining the changes.

**[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pto2nyh/)**

**html**

```
<div id="div">
  <button value="Add Row" id="button">Add row</button>
</div>
```

**js/jQuery**

```
var x = 1;
function appendRow() {
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + x);
// I ASSIGNED A CLASS CALLED INPUT TO THE ELEMENT YOU WANT TO SELECT
  newTextBoxDiv.after().html("<div class='form-group'><label class='control-label col-sm-3'  style='text-align:right;'>Date:</label><div class='col-sm-3'><div class='input-group date' ><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></span><input type='Date' class='form-control'  name='Dates'> <select class='form-control input' id='slct" + x + "' name='Branch''><option  disabled=''  selected=''>Please Select Leave Day</option> <option value='1' >1</option><option value='0.5' >0.5</option></select></div></span></div><div id='container" + x + "'></div></div>");
  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#div");
  x++;
}


function changeIt(rowIndex) {
    //i++; DO NOT INCREMENT I!!! IT WILL CREATE THE REFERRAL ERROR YOU HAD. BECAUSE THE FUNCTION WOULD BE REFERRING TO A NON-EXISTING INPUT ELEMENT. I REPLACED IT WITH ROWINDEX, WHICH IS INITIATED WHILE CALLING THE FUNCTION
  var select = document.getElementById("slct" + rowIndex);

  var divv = document.getElementById("container" + rowIndex);
  var value = select.value;

  if (value == 0.5) {
    toAppend = "<label class='control-label col-sm-1'>Time:</label><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'date'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control' ></div></div><div class='col-sm-2'><div class='input-group date' id = 'dates'> <span class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span><input type='time' class='form-control'  ></div></div>";
    divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
    return;
  }
  if (value == 1) {
    toAppend = "";
    divv.innerHTML = toAppend;
    return;
  }
}
$("#button").click(function(){
    appendRow();
});
$("#div").on("change",".input", function(){
   //EXTRACT THE NUMBER FROM THE CLICKED ITEM'S ID
   let rowIndex = $(this).attr("id").replace(/.[^0-9]/g, "");
  changeIt(rowIndex);
});
```

Comment: It's works fine in jsfiddle but when i put it my computer to run it's totally no response :(

Comment: @user3168370 If it works in JS-Fiddle there should be no reason for the same thing not to work in another environment. Have you checked if the function runs by running a console.log("test") at the start of the function? How are you invoking the function?

Comment: now it can be works fine already,since i move the script below the html code.Thanks for the suggestion given

Comment: You might want to use $( document ).ready()  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ . That ensures your code runs after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Put your 'return' outside of your `if` and before your final closing bracket.

```
if (value== 1) {
        toAppend = "";
        divv.innerHTML = toAppend;  
    }
return;
```